# auto_increment no longer increments

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

In a MySQL table the id column is set to auto_increment and the next auto_increment is set to 128 in phpmyadmin, but any new rows added have 127 as the value in the id row. I have no idea why.

Changed the column from tiny-int to int and everything working now, cheers.

Comment: Could you post the results of "show create table TABLE_NAME;"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is the columns type? I hope you didn't use tinyint :-) 
You should use int or number instead.

Comment: Yep, sounds like tinyint to me too!

Comment: indeed it is a tinyint column, didn't know that'd be a problem

Comment: tinyint has a range from -128 to +127, so is is not very well suited for auto_increment columns..